# App Crashes from playstore

Tags: android, google-play, noclassdeffounderror, zipalign

I have an app..I exported the signed apk and uploaded to play store.. When I run signed apk from my computer, it runs fine, but when I download the same from play store, it crashes... I connected the log-cat, it says no classdef found for one of my classes.. But I checked my manifest many times.. I have defined the class there.
What shall I do

Below is my logcat-

[image: Log Cat]

And below is my manifest where the class is defined.

[image: Manifest]

Comment: clean the project before making signed apk and publish it agian

Comment: post your LogCat full stacktrace

Comment: If the problem still persists give the whole path of your content provider in manifest like "app/qpals/adttech.group.MyFileContentProvider"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problems with eclipse, and each time I publish to Play Store, before uploading the APK **I verify that its built correctly**

You can do that by **installing the exported APK to your device** by using ADB and only after verifying the build works correctly should you upload it to Play Store

You can install the exported apk to your device by issuing the following commands in command prompt/adb

```
adb install build.apk
```

**where build.apk is the name of the built apk binary**

If you end up with build that fails to run(e.g. by similar exception you now received), try to "Clean Project" from eclipse's menu, it have helped me most of time with these kind of crashes after building

[image: image demonstrating how to clean eclipse project(s)]

Comment: Well i copied the signed exported apk to my device, installed it and it run properly.. Can you please tell me how can i install it using adb?

Comment: When you're in the folder where you've built your APK in command prompt(assuming you're running Windows) run the command "adb install FILENAME" where you replace FILENAME with the apk file name and don't include quotes

Comment: Also it shouldn't matter if you copy the APK over to device and install it, it should still work the same way

Was the one that you moved to your device and ran the exact same build you uploaded to Play Store?

Comment: AFAIK Google doesn't make any changes to the binaries, so the binay downloaded from Google Play should work as good as the one you install manually.. Its also possible that the file might be corrupted when transferring(I am pretty sure they verify them before publishing but if the stars aligned correctly..) So if I were you, I'd give it a new shot with the build you have pretested with your device before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76129/discussion-between-prakhar-and-pasi-matalamaki).